# Add-ons in HotJava Browser

Tags: firefox-addon

Can some body tell me : How to write an Add-on to a HotJava 3.0 Browser?.

I want to write an Add-on just like the ones for Mozilla FireFox. But for Sun HotJava.

Comment: Are there any hotjava tags on stackoverflow? Is this addon a fork of firefox?